# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape' while converting to array

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I was trying to predict classes but it is giving me this error.

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>        30         im=ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(205,45,585,555))
>        31         im.save('img.jpg')
>   ---> 32         predictions = new_model.predict([prepare('img.jpg')])
>        33         y=CATEGORIES[np.argmax(predictions[0][0])]
>        34
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py
>   in predict(self, x, batch_size, verbose, steps, callbacks,
>   max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)    1011
>   max_queue_size=max_queue_size,    1012         workers=workers,
>   -> 1013         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)    1014     1015   def reset_metrics(self):
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py
>   in predict(self, model, x, batch_size, verbose, steps, callbacks,
>   max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
>       496         model, ModeKeys.PREDICT, x=x, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose,
>       497         steps=steps, callbacks=callbacks, max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
>   --> 498         workers=workers, use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
>       499 
>       500
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py
>   in _model_iteration(self, model, mode, x, y, batch_size, verbose,
>   sample_weight, steps, callbacks, max_queue_size, workers,
>   use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
>       424           max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
>       425           workers=workers,
>   --> 426           use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
>       427       total_samples = _get_total_number_of_samples(adapter)
>       428       use_sample = total_samples is not None
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py
>   in _process_inputs(model, mode, x, y, batch_size, epochs,
>   sample_weights, class_weights, shuffle, steps, distribution_strategy,
>   max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
>       644     standardize_function = None
>       645     x, y, sample_weights = standardize(
>   --> 646         x, y, sample_weight=sample_weights)
>       647   elif adapter_cls is data_adapter.ListsOfScalarsDataAdapter:
>       648     standardize_function = standardize
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py
>   in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight,
>   batch_size, check_steps, steps_name, steps, validation_split, shuffle,
>   extract_tensors_from_dataset)    2344     # First, we build the model
>   on the fly if necessary.    2345     if not self.inputs:
>   -> 2346       all_inputs, y_input, dict_inputs = self._build_model_with_inputs(x, y)    2347       is_build_called =
>   True    2348     else:
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py
>   in _build_model_with_inputs(self, inputs, targets)    2570     else:
>   2571       cast_inputs = inputs
>   -> 2572     self._set_inputs(cast_inputs)    2573     return processed_inputs, targets, is_dict_inputs    2574
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py
>   in _set_inputs(self, inputs, outputs, training)    2645         first
>   layer isn't FeatureLayer.    2646     """
>   -> 2647     inputs = self._set_input_attrs(inputs)    2648     2649     if outputs is None:
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\training\tracking\base.py
>   in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
>       455     self._self_setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
>       456     try:
>   --> 457       result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
>       458     finally:
>       459       self._self_setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access
>
> ~\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py
>   in _set_input_attrs(self, inputs)    2684         input_shape =
>   (None,)    2685       else:
>   -> 2686         input_shape = (None,) + tuple(inputs.shape[1:])    2687       self._build_input_shape = input_shape    2688
>
> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'

```
import cv2
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

CATEGORIES = ["gas","back","both"]


def prepare(filepath):
    IMG_SIZE = 256
    img_array = cv2.imread(filepath)
    new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
    img = np.reshape(new_array,[1,256,256,3])
    return img


model = tf.keras.models.load_model("trained.model")

prediction = model.predict_classes([prepare('img.jpg')])
print(CATEGORIES[int(prediction[0])])
```

Comment: which line raises the exception?

Comment: Please post the error and the line producing error. There has to be a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 2):

You pass a list to `model.predict_classes` try giving it a numpy array instead:

```
prediction = model.predict_classes(prepare('img.jpg'))
```

Edit: apparently, your prepare function already has a first dim for the batch size so I removed the `[np.newaxis, :]`